# Android Creating a backdoor with specific keys?

Tags: android

In my application, I need to show a dialog, in case user presses an specific set of keys, e.g: 1234

Can anybody give me some idea where to begin?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is what I have done, I dunno if there are any backdoor specific APIs available.

clearly my pass is 1987

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1) {
    mState = 1;
} 

if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_9) {
    if (mState == 1) { 
        mState = 9;
    } else {
        mState = HIDE;
    }
} 

if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_8) {
    if (mState == 9) { 
        mState = 8;
    } else {
        mState = HIDE;
    }
} 

if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_7) {
    if (mState == 8) { 
        mState = SHOW;
    } else {
        mState = HIDE;
    }
} 

invalidateOptionsMenu();


return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

and then in onCreateOptionsMenu() :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu my_menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, my_menu);
    MenuItem item = my_menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
    if (mState == SHOW) {
        item.setVisible(true);
    }
    else if (mState == HIDE){
        item.setVisible(false);
    }


    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(my_menu);
}
```

Any better Idea is much appreciated.